# Babel Parser failing with "Unexpected token '('" on react app with npm build and npm start

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, unexpected-token

I was working on a feature for a react app and then stopped the node server, ran `npm run build` and got the following:

```
C:\Users<pathtomyapp>\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:8710
   (    at: this.state.startLoc
   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users<pathtomyapp>\node_modules\@babel\template\lib\parse.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)

Node.js v17.3.0
```

I get the same error if I try run `npm run start` now as well. Even if I switch git branches. I have no clue what is causing this error. The dev server was running just fine before I stopped it to build. Any suggestions?

node version: v17.3.0
npm version: 8.19.2

app was built with create-react-app

I tried...

1. Installing react-app-rewired
2. creating a .env file and adding 'SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true"
3. switching git branches
4. upgrading to node v20.3.0
5. upgrading to npm 9.7.1